# Zeros of complex functions - simple question

Tags: complex-analysis

I know this is easy one but I can't get to the bottom of it. A zero of a real function is when its value is equal to zero. But what is a complex zero? When the real part of its value is equal to zero OR when its imaginary part is equal to zero OR both must be zero?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A complex zero is a number $z$ such that $f(z) = 0$, where we mean $0 = 0 + 0i.$

Comment: You've answered my question! Thanks! So it's both.

Comment: You can post your answer in the main section so I can approve it.

Comment: Simple, but good question.

Comment: “Complex zero” usually refers to the *domain.* For example, $f(x) = x^2 +1$ has no real zeros, but two complex zeros ($ i$ and $-i$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was reluctant to post an answer, but I guess I can give more details than I did in my comment.

We have to remember that the complex number system has two parts - the real and imaginary parts. Whenever we write the symbol $x$ to mean a real number in this system, we regard it as the number $x + 0i,$ that is, the number whose real part is $x$ and imaginary part is $0.$

So, when we refer to a complex zero of a function, we mean a number $z$ such that $f(z) = 0$. While this doesn't seem to fit, we need to remember that the symbol $0$ is really the complex number that serves as the additive identity in $\mathbb{C}.$ So, we mean $0 = 0 + 0i$ as the complex number whose real and imaginary parts are both zero.

Comment: “Complex zero” usually refers to the *domain.* For example, $f(x) = x^2 +1$ has no real zeros, but two complex zeros ($ i$ and $-i$).

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite like the other answer. We do **not** merely "regard" a real $x$ as $x+0i$. Neither should we think of "$0$" as merely a symbol representing "the complex number that serves as the additive identity in $ℂ$".

In actual fact, when we construct $ℂ$ we **want** $ℝ ⊆ ℂ$ **literally**. The claim is that there *exists* a field $ℂ$ that **directly contains** $ℝ$ and has some $i∈ℂ$ such that $i^2+1 = 0$. Here, both the $0$ and $1$ are **exactly the same** zero and one in $ℝ$! That is the whole point of complex numbers! It is non-trivial, but such a field exists and when we write "$ℂ$" we literally mean such a field!

So $0 = 0+0i$, and there is no "interpretation" or "regarding" at all. We define a **complex zero** of a function $f$ on $ℂ$ to be some $z∈ℂ$ such that $f(z) = 0$. I want to emphasize again that this $0$ is **exactly the same zero** as the natural number $0$, or the real number $0$.

The only reason we call it "complex zero" is to distinguish it from "real zero", which refers to some $x∈ℝ$ such that $f(x) = 0$. Still the same $0$! The only difference is that we are looking for real $x$.